# How to make my static website public in wamp

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, wampserver

I am trying to make my static website in wamp public. In other tutorials, I saw that there's an option to make online/offline in httpd.conf. I dont see that now.

I changed the `Listens 80` to `Listens: 168.25.365..`(private IP). But the wamp is yellow.

What do I need to make wamp server public?

Comment: public meaning accessible by everyone in the internet?

Comment: @CarlBinalla yes

Comment: You need to upload your website on hosting.

Comment: Or you can try ngrok - https://ngrok.com/

Comment: @CarlBinalla here https://www.top10-websitehosting.co.uk/how-to-host-your-own-website   it says its possible

Comment: @CarlBinalla please tell me how I can host a static website on my local pc which is accessible over internet.

Comment: Why don't you just follow the instructions you just linked to?

Comment: @DwightSchrute I retract my comment regarding WampServer, it seems that it can really serve live websites. Regardless, this question is still too broad for StackOverflow

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I dont see the `Order Deny, Allow` part in `httpd.conf` file. Maybe the newer version does not have it?

Comment: If you don't see it, you should be able to add yourself. It's likely that the default config simply doesn't use it.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* make your wamp public, but it is ill advisable. WAMP is a developer's tool, to easily administer and install Apache, MySQL, and PHP on a windows machine.

To host your website, you need to host in on a publicly accessible host (still with a webserver (e.g. apache og nginx), with PHP and MySQL backend). This will require you to upload your code via scp or ftps and then configure your database via e.g. phpmyadmin.

If you REALLY want your wamp to be public, you need to keep your pc on, forward a port in your router (assuming something like NAT, unless your router gives you a publicly adressable IP), and opening firewalls etc. There are many reasons that this is a bad idea, among others that your PC is vulnerable to any attacks that the apache server in wamp is vulnerable to.

If you realise that this is not what you want to do, please rephrase your question to allow us to help you get an answer.